# Adding a row above 1st counted instance - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to write a script which will enable me to add a single row above the 1st counted instance of a unique value.

Eg.

```
    A
    German
    German
    German
    Italian
    Italian
    French
    French
```

After running the script it should resemble this:

```
    A
    DE
    German
    German
    German
    IT
    Italian
    Italian
    FR
    French
    French
```

What I have written has only gotten as far as identifying how many values are present:

```
function insertRowAbove() 
 {
 var report = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('REPORT');

 var lang = report.getRange('A10:A').getValues();
 var positions = report.getRange('A10:A').getA1Notation();
 var DE = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < lang.length; i++)
 {
  if (lang[i] == 'German') 
  {
    DE++
    report.getRange('A1').setValue(DE);//now I know there are 3 German entries
  }
 }
}
```

My question:
Is it possible for the script to know the A1notation of the 1st occurrence of a value and add a row above it? I thank you for any sagely advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specific question was:

> My question: Is it possible for the script to know the A1notation of
>   the 1st occurrence of a value and add a row above it?

By using a combination of a Boolean to indicate whether you've found *any* of the items you are looking for, and a couple of `Range` methods, you can get the A1notation of the first occurrence.

```
var column = 1; // this example is only using column A
var foundGerman = false;
var firstGerman = '';
...
if (lang[i] == 'German') {
  if (!foundGerman) {
    foundGerman = true;
    firstGerman = range.getCell(i, column).getA1Notation();
  }
  ...
}
```

After that, you will have the A1Notation of the first cell containing "German".

However, the function `insertRowsBefore()` is a `Sheet` method, and expects a row number as a parameter, not A1Notation. So figuring out what the address of the first German cell was turns out to be unnecessary.

### Script

Here's my entry in the contest! For speed, it's wise to use as few apps script service calls as possible. In this script, all data manipulation is done using arrays, with the final result written once.

In anticipation that you'll have more than three languages that you care about, and for maintainability, the language lookup is handled by an Object, `iso639`. (Assuming you're using [ISO 639-1 Language Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes).) As a result, the actual work takes just 10 lines of code!

```
function insertViaArray() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('REPORT');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newValues = [];

  var iso639 = 
    {
      "German" : "DE",
      "Italian" : "IT",
      "French" : "FR"
    }

  var curLang = '';
  for (var i in values) {
    if (values[i][0] !== curLang) {
      curLang = values[i][0];
      newValues.push([iso639[curLang]]);
    }
    newValues.push([values[i][0]]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newValues.length, 1).setValues(newValues)
};
```

**Edit** Script V2

By using `Array.splice()` to insert the language tags, we can further reduce the code to 8 working lines, and eliminate the need for a parallel `newValues` array.

```
function insertViaArrayV2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('REPORT');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var iso639 = 
    {
      "German" : "DE",
      "Italian" : "IT",
      "French" : "FR"
    }

  var curLang = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] !== curLang) {
      curLang = values[i][0];
      values.splice(i, 0, [iso639[curLang]]);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, 1).setValues(values)
};
```

Comment: *Here's my entry in the contest!* ... and the winner is... Mogsdad ! for this iso trick and compactness! just a note : I didn't take the array solution because I was thinking that there are probably more data on this sheet and/or some formatting... that's why I kept the api calls in the loop. Anyway, +1 for aforementioned reason ;)

Comment: @Sergeinsas - thanks! But you know, if the data isn't ordered, none of our solutions will work...

Comment: If I was wearing a top hat I would tip it to you @Mogsdad Good thing that the data will always be ordered alphabetically otherwise it would be a nightmare! I have tried your solution and is it correct in assuming it re-arranges the data rather than adding a row above the first instance?

Comment: @Julz no spreadsheet rows are added in this approach. Instead, all labels are spliced into the array representation of the sheet data, and the final result is set into a new (larger) range that overwrites the original.

Answer (score 2):

The following works (see [EXAMPLE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmR0r1Y14zgydG03QS1Dd0dLRDA3SWgtLXp6TzV3d3c#gid=2)):

```
function insertRowAbove() {
 var report = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Insert Row Above');
 var values = report.getRange('B2:B').getValues();

 var prevVal = "null"; 
 var index = 1;
 while (index < values.length) {
   if (values[index].toString() != prevVal.toString()) {

     var header = 'unknown';
     if (values[index] == 'German')
       header = 'DE';
     else if (values[index] == 'Italian')
       header = 'IT';
     else if (values[index] == 'French')
       header = 'FR';

     report.insertRowBefore(index+1);
     report.getRange(index+1, 2).setValue(header);
     values = report.getRange('B2:B').getValues();
     index++;
   }
   prevVal = values[index];
   index++;
 }

}
```

Comment: I think you left a typo in your code : `var values = report.getRange('B2:B').getValues();` should have been `var values = report.getRange('A2:A').getValues();` right ?

Comment: No, I was using Column A to keep an original copy of the data. Column B was the working copy.

Comment: @opowell This solution was ingenious, however unusable for my particular purpose - thank you for the lovely alternative!

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a funny exercise and, as usual, there are probably many ways to get it working.

I'm not pretending my approach is better, it's just different and therefor it it probably worth showing it here ;-)

```
function testFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getRange('A10:A').getValues();
  var rowNum = 11;
  var previous = data[0][0];
  Logger.log(data)
 sh.insertRowBefore(10);
 sh.getRange(2,1).setValue(firstLetters(data[0][0]));
  for(n=1;n<data.length;++n){
  if(data[n][0].replace(/ /g,'')==previous.replace(/ /g,'')){
     previous = data[n][0] ; 
     ++rowNum ; 
     continue ; 
     }else if(firstLetters(data[n][0])){
     sh.insertRowBefore(rowNum+1);
     sh.getRange(rowNum+1,1).setValue(firstLetters(data[n][0]));
     ++rowNum
     previous = data[n][0]
     ++rowNum
     Logger.log(rowNum+'  '+firstLetters(data[n][0]))
     }else{
     break
     }
}
}

function firstLetters(name){
if (name==''){return false}
var str = name.toString().replace(/ /g,'').toUpperCase().substring(0,2);
if (str=='GE') {str='DE'};// handle german exception
if (str=='PO'){ str='PT'} ;//handle portuguese exception
return str;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for the late reply! After testing your solution it appears that the script decides to add the string two lines above the required position.. would you be able to see what is going wrong? I have edited my original post to show you the current script. @Serge

Comment: I replaced with an updated version with some small enhancements, starting on row 10 - it worked as expected on my testsheet - see [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dFRDb2NCX3NqMmdmYU5TclNsSXZOUWc&usp=sharing)

Comment: I changed it to `var rowNum = 12` in your original solution and it worked ;)

Comment: ok, but think about taking the updated version as it adds a "replace" in the condition to ensure there is not risk of error on 'hidden' spaces ;-)

Comment: Aye aye captain! As usual, you have my virtual e-respect